# How to edit the config.xml to enable android debugging in phonegap build?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build, phonegap

From my understanding, I have to add

```
<application android:debuggable="true" />
```

To the  `AndroidManifest.xml`

I have added the following to my `config.xml`

```
<config-file platform="android" parent="/manifest" mode="merge">
    <application android:debuggable="true" />
</config-file>
```

But that hasn't worked

Comment: what "hasn't worked" ?

Comment: Have you added xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" to widget tag? That allows to taggle the android:debuggable setting.